# Can't open link saved to QR code on Google Goggles

Tags: qr-code, smartphone, google-goggles

I generated a QR code for this link:

http://www.ideahouse.com.my/proddetail.asp?id=PP&pid=5850565C&productid=1925

through Quikqr.com

But when I use Google Goggles, it copies this this much of the address:

http://www.ideahouse.com.myproddetail.asp?id=PP

It also generates the following error:

ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bcd'

Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

/proddetail.asp/line 144

Is there anyone out there who can shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using a different generator for the QR code?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I went to another QR code website and it worked!

Comment: @user23 Post it as a answer that you tried.

Comment: @mtk no answer needed I believe. The question should be closed as off topic as it isn't programming related. It's just a buggy online tool.